# Renaming filenames in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So im trying to make a program through Tkinter where the user can manipulate through the file system. I have separate codes for the other buttons that are not working, but the rename button is giving me a hard time. How could i close the filedialog in this code?

Here's my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys,glob,time,os
from tkinter import filedialog

def dir2():
    global direc
    direc=filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/",title="Choose directory")
    dire1.config(text=direc)
    print(direc)
    mainloop()

def cancelr():
    rrf.destroy()
    root.deiconify()

def rnf():
    name1=os.path.basename(rpath.name)
    filee=None
    for filee in glob.glob(name1):
        if os.path.isdir(filee)==False:
            os.rename(name1,nfn.get())
            print("done")
        elif file == None:
            print("nothing")

def rf():
    global fn
    global rrf
    global rpath
    global name1
    nfn=StringVar()
    nfn.set(" ")
    rpath=filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=direc,title="Rename a file")
    os.chdir(direc)
    rrf=Toplevel(root)
    root.iconify()
    rrf.geometry('350x100+500+200')
    body=Frame(rrf)
    body.pack()
    Label(body,text="Enter new file name: ",font=("Arial",15)).pack()
    nfname=Entry(body,textvariable=nfn, width=50 ).pack()
    body2=Frame(rrf)
    body2.pack()
    Button(body2,text="Done", font=   ("Arial",10),command=rnf).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=4)
    Button(body2,text="Cancel",font=("Arial",10),command=cancelr).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=4)
    mainloop()

 def creation():
    os.chdir(direc)
    fname=fn.get()
    file=open(fname,"w")
    file.close
    done=messagebox.askyesno("File created!","Continue creating file?")
    if done==True:
        return
    else:
        crf.destroy()
        root.deiconify()

def cancelc():
    crf.destroy()
    root.deiconify()
def df():
    dfname=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=direc,title="Choose a  file")
    done=messagebox.askyesno("Confirm","Delete file?")
    if done==True:
        os.remove(dfname)
        messagebox.showinfo("Success!","File deleted")
    else:
        return
def cf():
    global fn
    global crf
    fn=StringVar()
    fn.set(" ")
    crf=Toplevel(root)
    root.iconify()
    crf.geometry('350x100+500+200')         
    body=Frame(crf)
    body.pack()
    Label(body,text="Enter file name: ",font=("Arial",15)).pack()
    fname=Entry(body,textvariable=fn, width=50, ).pack()
    body2=Frame(crf)
    body2.pack()
    Button(body2,text="Done", font=    ("Arial",10),command=creation).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=4)
    Button(body2,text="Cancel",font=("Arial",10),command=cancelc).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=4)

    print(fname)
    mainloop()

def qui():
    exit()


def butttons():
    create=Button(body, text="Create file",command=cf,font=("Arial",12))
    create.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=4)
    de=Button(body,text="Delete file",font=("Arial",12),command=df)
    de.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5,pady=4)
    body2=Frame(root)
    body2.pack()
    re=Button(body2,text="Rename",font=("Arial",12),command=rf)
    re.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=6,pady=4)
    ld=Button(body2,text="List directory",font=("Arial",12))
    ld.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=3,pady=4)
    body3=Frame(root)
    body3.pack()
    tr=Button(body3,text="Traverse",font=("Arial",12))
    tr.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=4,padx=12)
    se=Button(body3,text="Search file",font=("Arial",12))
    se.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=4,padx=9)
    body4=Frame(root)
    body4.pack()
    qu=Button(body4,text="Quit",command=qui,font=("Arial",12))
    qu.pack()



def dirr():
    global dire1
    global brow1
    global direc
    direc=StringVar()
    direc=filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/",title="Choose directory")
    print(direc)
    brow.destroy()
    gs.destroy()
    desc.destroy()
    dire1=Label(header, text=direc, font=("Arial",10),
          relief=SUNKEN,anchor=W, justify=LEFT,width=30)
    dire1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    brow1=Button(header,text="Browse", command=dir2,font=("Arial",10))
    brow1.grid(row=0,column=2)
    butttons()
    mainloop()


root=Tk()
root.title("File Systems")
root.geometry('300x200+100+50')
header=Frame(root)
header.pack()
gs=Label(header,text='''
Getting Started''',font=("Arial",17))
gs.pack(anchor="center")
body=Frame(root)
body.pack()
desc=Label(body,text='''
Choose a directory:''',font=("Arial",12))
desc.pack()
brow=Button(body, text=("Browse"),font=("Arial",10),command=dirr)
brow.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: what does "giving me a hard time" mean?

Comment: at least one problem is that you're calling `mainloop` more than once. You should always call it exactly once in your program.

Comment: Please only provide a minimal working example. The other functionalities of your program is totally uninteresting to this question.

Comment: sorry, im kinda new to the python, the problem here is that when i run this program and choose the rename button, it says that the file i am renaming is being used by another program.